# How to make SVG image to use available space? (and to avoid size-hardcoding)

Tags: flutter, svg, resize

I have an SVG image as a child (at the begin) of a Row. I have wrapped it in a FractionallySizedBox() to make sure that image takes a certain amount of space in a Row. Now, I want Image to use that space, without setting fix width or height (since it can make problems on different devices).
I have used attribute fit: BoxFit.scaleDown, but it is not working.

Any suggestions? :)

here my code:

```
      Row(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: FractionallySizedBox(
                widthFactor: 0.65,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/image.svg',
                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown
                       //width: 60,
                      ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(item.name,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                        textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                    Text(
                      item.type,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                    ),
                  ]),
            ),
```

Comment: as you have used expanded in row it will take all the available space in the row.

Comment: Instead of `FractionallySizedBox` did you try [flex](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flexible/flex.html): ...?

Comment: No, I didn't. I'm gonna take a look how it works with flex.
EDIT: I have managed to solve it by wrapping a image with Fitted box and with: fit: BoxFit.cover. Only, it is pretty much nested now and I would like to consider some more elegant solution :D

Comment: instead of wrapping it with fittedBox you can directly give BoxFit.cover to fit property of SvgPicture.asset()